# Limit of $\frac{n^{a}}{b^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $a,b\in{\\N}, b>1$, I'm asked to find the limit of the sequence defined as

$x_{n}=\frac{n^a}{b^n}$

Isn't enough to say that, since $b>1,\frac{1}{b}<1$ and using the fact that if $|x|<1$, then $\lim_{n} x=0$, then the limit of $x_{n}=\frac{1}{b^n}n^a$ is 0?

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Comment: Not quite. Since $n^a$ is increasing to infinity, you can't just rely on the fact that the denominator is increasing to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0$ then $x_n=\dfrac 1{b^n}\to 0$

If $a\neq 0$ let's set $c=b^{\frac 1a}$ then $x_n=\left(\dfrac n{c^n}\right)^a$

Since $b>1$ then $c>1$, we can rewrite $c=1+u$ with $u>0$.

$c^n=(1+u)^n=1+nu+\frac {n(n-1)}2u^2+\underbrace{...}_{\text{other positive terms}}\ge \frac{n(n-1)}2u^2$

Thus $\dfrac{c^n}n\ge \frac 12(n-1)u^2\to\infty$ consequently $x_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The same argument might be made for the sequence
$$
y_n=\frac{n^a}{(n+1)^a}
$$
The denominator, $(n+1)^a$, goes to infinity, and $|y_n|\lt1$. However,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=1
$$